# Are anti-DDoS rules unnecessary if NEW state connections are dropped on the INPUT and FORWARD chains?

Tags: iptables, router, ddos

Scenario: A router is used to connect internal clients to the Internet. The router does not provide open services to the Internet.

Let's say you have iptables rules like the ones below and no others.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i <wan_face> -m state --NEW -j DROP
```

Below is an example of an anti-DDoS rule.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
```

Are anti-DDoS rules unnecessary if NEW state connections are dropped on the INPUT and FORWARD chains over the wan_face ?

Comment: You cannot protect yourself from DDoS by using firewall rules.

Comment: @Anubioz You can protect things behind your firewall from some DDoS attacks with rules, probably wouldn't be on the INPUT chain though.

Comment: @Zoredache Well, by DDoS I mean bandwidth flood attacks, that would overflow your connection no matter what firewall rules you have. Those attacks that your can shrug off with your firewall should be called [Application-Layer DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Application-layer_floods) - they indeed can be filtered by either using rules, or better by optimizing your application :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why specify any additional rules at all if you set the default policy to DROP?

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

That policy is one that would normally be followed only by a number of **exceptions** to the default DROP policy, i.e. incoming traffic that you want to allow in...

If you don't have any exceptions why bother at all with further inspecting your traffic.

The only thing your so-called DDOS protection rules do is requiring additional processing (potentially even increasing the effectiveness of a DDOS attack).

Your logic now looks like:

```
if (something) then 
     DROP
else if (something_else) then 
     DROP
else if (something_else) then 
     DROP
else if (something_else) then 
     DROP
fi

# For everything that wasn't caught by the previous rules:
DROP any way
```

which is a bit silly, right?

Comment: That's what I thought. I was searching for examples to harden a router with iptables rules. The firewall scripts that I found had a lot of anti-DDoS and network health rules that made sense since their sites had open ports on the wan_face. However, since the router I'm configuring has no open ports on the wan_face, I wanted to make sure I could dispense with an excessive amount of unnecessary rules and just DROP NEW (state) incoming connections.